# Lazarus(Pascal) RunError(5)

Tags: pascal, lazarus

My program exits with RunError(5), which would suggest that it can't access the file, which it should be able to. I have checked and the file is used as it should be, the file isn't read-only, etc. What the program does is, it creates a .dat file if one doesn't exists and uses it for saving stuff. If I run the program and the file doesn't exist, the file is created, but after that, in the same execution, the program won't access the file. This ONLY happens if the file was created in the current execution.

This is the way in which the procedures are called(the code is quite long but I am giving you the first few lines, where the error occurs):

```
 fileName := 'labSave.dat';
 CreateFile;
 assign(labyrinthFile,fileName);
 writeln(CheckFileSize);
```

and then there is each of the procedures:

```
procedure Initialize;
begin
    fileName := 'labSave.dat';
    assign(labyrinthFile,fileName);
end;   

procedure CreateFile;
begin
    if not FileExists(fileName) then FileCreate(fileName);
end; 

function CheckFileSize: integer;
begin
    reset(labyrinthFile);
    CheckFileSize := FileSize(labyrinthFile);
    close(labyrinthFile);
end;
```

Comment: It actually wasn't assigned because I rearranged my program and left out the assign, but now I fixed it and it still does the same thing, but the error occurs in the FileSize() part. Edited post.

Comment: Am I right, that if file does not exists, you `assign()` it **first** and create it **after** that? So the created file is not getting `assign()`. That is clearly a design bug ;)

Comment: You are right but I am not sure if this matters, because as I see it, the labyrinthFile will always be assigned to that name even if it isn't created yet. Anyway, tried creating a file with fileName and then assigning it to labyrinthFile. Still doesn't work :(. I suppose if the error is 5, then there must be a reason for it not being able to access the file, but why wouldn't it be able to access something exactly after it was created I don't know. There may be a reason.

Comment: The assignment is working by binding a file to a var, not a filename. Hence the assign must be after create in ANY way. You need to show your file creation code as well.

Comment: I edited the post the way you told me to do it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you close the file during the first access? Every reset must be matched by a close.

Comment: I do, I think I found a way around the problem. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Lazarus forum (http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=4936.0):

> Runtime Error 5 means Access denied. The file maybe readonly and you
>   use the wrong (default) filemode, or you try to re-open the file with
>   a new filehandle without having closed it before (somewhere in the
>   while and repeat loops possibly you assignfile more then once, then
>   the reset fails?).

If I recall correctly now, the workflow should be as follows for create:

`AssignFile(f, filename); Rewrite(f); CloseFile(f);`

and for existing file:

`AssignFile(f, filename); Reset(f); CloseFile(f);`

Seeing other mistakes found in your code through questions in comments, I strongly suggest you to devote more time to debugging and when such errors happen - strip out ALL of the irrelevant code and check your code design for cases like above (assigning file before creating it, etc.).

Comment: If that answer helped you, you can upvote it. If it solved your problem - mark it as accepted ;) Either way, give us a note when you find what was wrong!

Comment: I am not completely sure what the problem is. I think that it may be the FileCreate(I found about it online, so I had no experience with the procedure, probably that is part of the problem). It seems to create a file that can't be immediately read. In my case I was able to work around the problem using rewrite() to create the file. Thank you for your time anyway.